# MySql : autoincrement gets its original value when mysql server stops

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a Mysql table autoincrement that is set to its initial value each time the mysql server is stopped.
I have read this is a normal behaviour for Mysql.

Is there a way to avoid this? Is it possible to set a value (max+1 from another table ) at mysql server start to set the autoincrement to "value + 1" it was just before the server stopped?

Thanks

Comment: That does not sound like normal behaviour. Can you provide the code you are using + the create table statement?

Comment: can u add ur create table struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes the counter for each table for the first INSERT to the table

Comment: Wow, learn something new every day. Of course, if people aren't storing references to non-existent data, this won't be an issue.